# Check something before django server starts

Tags: django

I am running my api behind a django server and say I have a one time token that is needed by the django application and used through out its existence until the process quits. To check if I can proceed and serve requests (using the django server) I need to validate this token against a database entry. Now, I can have a script that hits the db, then issues the run server command if the token is valid. But if the db used by the django applications change, I will have to change the script also to point to the same db.

Is there a way I can pass this token into the runserver command as an additional parameter (along with hostname:port) and validate this before django serves any requests? How can I access this parameter that is sent into ./manage.py runserver.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll find that anything you try to fix in `runserver` won't work when you deploy for real.

Comment: Hmm.. So can the django app's settings be used before the runserver is executed? Is that safe? If yes, I can use the same setting to query the database before issuing the runserver command.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the token via environmental variable -- it'll work in both development and production setup without any code changes.

Comment: Sorry, but the requirement is not to expose the token anywhere and it should be a secret. It should only reside in the memory of the django apps and not be exposed manually.